# Can digital signature contain '.' (dot) character?

Tags: digital-signature

I'm wondering if a digital signature can contain a dot (`.`) character? (like this: `abcd.kdjksjsdf`)

Answer (score 2):

"Digital signature" is a broad term, as the signatures themselves are created with different cryptographic algorithms, and then are wrapped into different structures.

The signature (as a product of the cryptographic operation) is always binary. Most wrapping formats are binary as well. In some rare cases (eg. in OpenPGP) the format offers some optional text-based (BASE16 or BASE64 most often) encoding of the binary signature.

So the question of the "dot" doesn't make much sense. Of course the byte with the value of 0x2E (46 dec) is possible in the signature, as the signature may contain any byte value. A byte with value 0x2E would be interpreted as a dot when the signature is *viewed as* ASCII compatible text.

Whether a dot is possible in a particular encoding to text of the signature depends on the encoding scheme. The regular base 64 encoding doesn't contain dots, only alphanumerics and the `+`, `\` or `=` characters.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS  for your answering. I just use RSAwithSHA1 to create a signature in java program, and get an string result. So I want to know if the '.' character could be included in this string result (because I use '.' to split signature with other fileds)

Comment: @phuc that signature is binary.  How you convert it to text and accordingly what it can contain is up to you.